# Is the plural of 'prefix' really 'prefixes' rather than 'prefices'?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, suffixes, latin

It [looks like](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prefix?s=t) the plural of 'prefix' is 'prefixes' - while I would expect it to be

'prefix' => 'prefices' like
'matrix' => 'matrices' or
'index'  => 'indices'.

Is 'prefix' an exception to the rule? If so, why?

Comment: Affix is also affixes.

Comment: Interesting! My *guess* is that the accepted plurals are evolved based on pronunciation. Prefix is indeed not the only exception. Someone with an identical question on another forum: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plural-of-prefix-suffix-and-other-ix-words.569981/

Comment: There is a very brief reference to *prefices* in the OED - but it simply refers you back to *prefix* without any discussion. The only plural examples I noticed showed it as being *prefixes* - similarly *suffixes*.

Comment: Note that _reflex_ doesn't follow _index_, _vertex_, _cortex_, etc. in (sometimes) having an **-ices** plural.

Comment: *Index* itself has plural *indexes* when referring to the reference table (according to both the OED and the Society of Indexers). Those who expect English to have universal rules are doomed to disappointment

Comment: @TimLymington: I agree with your comment about universal rules, but I've always known the plural of 'index' to be 'indices'. I see this in computer code all the time, and here's the reference: https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/?word=indices&search_word_type=Dictionary (If you don't have a subscription to the Macquarie, the Cambridge dictionary also includes a reference: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indices )

Comment: _Prefices_ would be completely unetymological in every way. In addition to sumelic’s point that the Latin form is _praefixum_, which is neuter and pluralises with _-a_, the root is _fig-_ and has never at any point had a c anywhere. Even if the Latin word had been third-declension _praefix_, its plural would have ***praefiges***.

Comment: _Prefices_ would be completely unetymological in every way. In addition to sumelic’s point that the Latin form is _praefixum_, which is neuter and pluralises with _-a_, the root is _fig-_ and has never at any point had a _c_ anywhere. Even if the Latin word had been third-declension praefix, its plural would have been ***praefiges***, not _*praefices_.

Comment: My dictionary shows plural of *matrix* is *matrices* or *matrixes*.  Similar for *appendixes* and *indexes*.  Indeed, it says *indices* is used especially in technical contexts.

Comment: @TimLymington Isn't that more of an Americanism? Given the U.S. influence on modern computing, and their propensity to drop similar words/spellings from the English lexicon, it's not surprising that many don't know that the verb and noun are differentiable.

Comment: @Walf: if anything, I would say that universal *indices* is the Americanism; rooted, as Michael Scheper says, in computer jargon. Distinguishing the two nouns is important for anybody who is fond both of books and of numbers, which is not geographically determined.

Comment: @TimLymington My experience has been the opposite, where, typically American texts use *indexes* for both noun and verb.

Comment: @walf; Experience is not arguable. But if you are really referring to the verb you have misread the question.

Comment: @TimLymington I don't believe I've misread anything. I came here wanting to know more about why *prefixes* is the correct plural. I noticed you said "*Index* itself has plural *indexes*", whereas I have only ever seen *indexes* as being the verb for creating an index. The exception to this is in computing where many use it also for the plural noun, which I see as a mistake in the same vein as "could care less".

Comment: There is little point in arguing opinions, which is why my original comment cited authorities.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## General principle: Latin plural forms go with Latin singular forms

The plural of the Latin word [*matrix*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matrix#Inflection) is *matrices*, and the plural of the Latin word [*index*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/index#Declension) is *indices*. We took the singular forms of these words from Latin unchanged, and the same goes for the plural forms (unchanged in the spelling, anyway; the pronunciation has been anglicized).

But *prefix* is not the singular form of any Latin word. The Latin word it is derived from is [*praefix**um***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praefixus#Latin), and the plural of that is not *praefices*, it's *praefix**a***. Since no Latin plural form *pr(a)efices* exists, the English plural form is just made by combining the singular form *prefix* and the normal English plural suffix *-(e)s*: *prefixes.*

From the Online Etymology Dictionary entry on [*prefix* (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prefix&allowed_in_frame=0):

> 1640s, from Latin *praefixum*, noun use of neuter past participle of
> *praefigere* "fix in front, fasten on before," from *prae* "before" (see
> *pre-*) + root of *figere* "to fasten, fix" (see *fix* (v.)).

Compare this to the entries on the origins of

- *[matrix](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=matrix&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> late 14c., "uterus, womb," from Old French *matrice* "womb, uterus," from **Latin *matrix* (genitive
> *matricis*)** "pregnant animal," in Late Latin "womb," also "source,
> origin," from mater (genitive matris) "mother" (see mother (n.1))[...]

- [*index*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=index&allowed_in_frame=0):

> late 14c., "the forefinger," from **Latin *index* (genitive *indicis*)**
> "forefinger, pointer, sign, list," literally "anything which points
> out," from *indicare* "point out" (see indication). Meaning "list of a
> book's contents" is first attested 1570s, from Latin phrases such as
> *Index Nominum* "Index of Names," *index expurgatorius* "specification of
> passages to be deleted from works otherwise permitted."[...]

### Other words that pluralize like *prefix*

#### *-ex* words

[Sven Yargs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277945/is-the-plural-of-prefix-really-prefixes-rather-than-prefices/277951#comment615200_277945) left a comment mentioning another English word derived from Latin that has a singular form ending in "x" and a regular plural form ending in "xes": *reflex.*

Some other nouns that do not take a plural in *-ices* even though the last two letters of the English singular are *-ex* are

- *[circumflex](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=circumflex)* from Latin *circumflexus*
- *[complex](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complex)* from Latin *complexus*
- *[duplex](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplex), [multiplex](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiplex)* from Latin *duplex, multiplex*
- *[annex](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=annex)* from Latin *annexus* or *annexum* (and its derivative, French *annexe*)
- and the monosyllable *sex* from Latin *sexus* (and it derivative, French *sexe*).

Most of these word come from either Latin participles of the first/second declension or the corresponding nouns of the fourth declension. *Duplex* is an interesting case: it is from a Latin adjective *duplex* "twofold" that did have a plural form *duplices,* but the word was taken into English as an adjective, and English adjectives don't have plural forms. Then when the English adjective was converted to a noun, it acquired the regular English plural form *duplexes.*

#### *-ix* words

Aside from the other *-fix* words (*[affix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affix), [suffix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suffix), [postfix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/postfix), [infix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infix), [antefix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antefix), [superfix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superfix), [subfix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subfix), [crucifix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crucifix)* etc.), I can't find any more Latin-derived nouns ending in *-ix* that lack (standardly recognized) plural forms in *-ices.* Such words would be expected to come from sources like Latin nouns ending in *-ixus, ixum* or perhaps *-ixa.*

#### *-ax, -ox, -ux* words

As far as I know, there are no English words ending in *-ax, -ox*, or *-ux* that commonly take plural forms in *-ces,* even though there are some Latin words ending in these letters that pluralized this way (e.g. *fornax, fornaces* "furnace", *vox, voces* "voice", *crux, cruces* "cross", *dux, duces* "leader").

The word *[syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65541)* and *flux* don't come from Latin words ending in *-x* (they are from *syntaxis* and *fluxus*), and so the absence of *"syntaces" and *"fluces" as plural forms is expected.

The Latin form of the word *climax* does end in *-x*, and so there's no way in theory to rule out the Latin/Greek-based plural form *climaces* as a possibility for the English plural, but in practice *climaxes* seems to be the only possibility for the vast majority of present-day speakers. *Climaces* apparently was used in Kinsey, Pomeroy, and Martin's *Sexual Behavior in the Human Male* (first published 1948, copyright renewed 1975; accessed through [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=pfMKrY3VvigC&pg=PA215&dq=#v=onepage&q=climaces&f=false)).

## Exceptions to this general principle

The general principle I give above is not absolutely accurate. Not everyone is aware of this principle, or follows it all the time, and there are complicating factors like analogy. Interestingly, Wiktionary does list "[prefices](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefices)" as a ("nonstandard") plural form of "prefix". So it apparently has seen some use.

There are some other (rather odd) possible exceptions in English to the general rule that Latin plural forms are only used when the corresponding Latin singular form is used.

#### *Antipodes* (singular *antipode*)

The word *antipode,* as far as I know, is only ever pronounced /⁠ˈæntɨˌpoʊd⁠/ "ANT-ih-poad"). But the singular form *antipode* is less common than the plural form *antipodes*, which coincidentally has an ambiguous written form: it corresponds equally well to the regular English *-(e)s* plural and the Latin plural form ending in *-es.*

The OED says that the original English pronunciation of the plural form *antipodes* was probably regular (/⁠ˈæntɨˌpoʊdz⁠/ "ANT-ih-poads"), and compares it to the French word *antipode/antipodes* (which is formed in the regular way for a French plural). But it is most common nowadays to pronounce this word as if it were taken directly from the Latin plural form, giving /⁠ænˈtɪpədiːz⁠/ "an-TIP-uh-deez".

There seems to have been no (or at any rate, no attested) Latin singular form because the word was always used as a plural (it comes from the same "foot" root as *octopus,* which has the opposite issue of an [unclear Latin plural form](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/138236/77227)). So those who say Latin-based /ænˈtɪpədiːz/ for the plural have to fall back on non-Latin /ˈæntɨˌpoʊd/ for the singular.

#### *Mores* (no commonly accepted singular in English)

The word *mores*, as in "social mores," comes from the Latin *mores* "customs" (a plural word) and is prescriptively pronounced with two syllables, not one (either /ˈmoəriːz/ "MORE-eez" or /ˈmoəreɪz/ "MORE-ayz" is generally considered acceptable; I prefer the former but dictionaries suggest the latter is more common).

The dictionaries I have looked at say this word only possesses a plural form. The Latin singular form *mos* is never used in English, but you can sometimes see people use *more* as a singular in phrases like "a social more". I assume this would be pronounced /moər/ "moar" (though since I have only encountered it in writing, I don't know for sure).

Although I would not recommend the use of singular *more,* it would be another example of a word like *antipodes*/*antipode* where the plural is commonly pronounced as a Latinate form, but the singular never is.

#### *Magi* as a plural of *mage* in fantasy (possibly?), or as an invariant form

Latin had a word *magus,* with the regular plural *magi.* These forms have been taken into English as *magus* (pronounced in English /meɪgəs/ "MAY-guss") and *magi* (pronounced in English /meɪdʒaɪ/ "MAY-jye"), but these words are somewhat obscure. The anglicized form *mage* (pronounced /meɪdʒ/) has become fairly popular in fantasy fiction. And apparently some [fantasy writers](http://absolutewrite.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-53363.html) pair the anglicized singular form *mage* with the Latin plural form *magi,* although I believe it's more common for *mage* to get a standard English plural *mages* /meɪdʒɨz/.

This seems to be a case where some people use the Latin plural just because it sound fancier or is more fun to use. The Latin plural form *magi* is especially well known, and perhaps more familiar than the Latin singular form *magus,* because many people are familiar with the term "Magi" in reference to the Christian [Biblical Magi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Magi).

In Japanese, nouns do not change form based on singular and plural, and  マギ *magi* is used to refer either to Zoroastrian magi, the Christian magi, or a magus/magician in the context of fantasy. Fantasy-genre fiction translated from Japanese may therefore use *magi* as a singular noun, as well as its invariant plural, as in the manga series "[Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi:_The_Labyrinth_of_Magic)".

#### "Latinate" pronunciations of plural forms that aren't actually from Latin

Some words ending in a non—primary-stressed syllable followed by /s/, such as *process, bias, auspice, interstice,* have plural forms ending in *-es* that are pronounced by some speakers with /siːz/, as if they were Latin/Greek plural forms. But none of the singular forms of these words comes directly from Latin, and although *auspices* exists in Latin as the plural form corresponding to the singular *auspex,* this is just a coincidence: the English noun *auspice* comes from the distinct (but related) Latin noun *auspicium,* which doesn't mean the same thing as *auspex*.

I give a somewhat longer list of words where this pronunciation may be possible in my answer to the question *[What is the correct pronunciation of the word “processes”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/437851/77227)*

Comment: From google n-grams, "prefices" seems to have been a temporary (and little used) aberration of the 1940s and 1970s, dying out since them. (That surprised me - I would have guessed it was the 18th/19th century spelling.) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prefices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprefices%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @alephzero But oh-so-insignificant: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prefices%2Cprefixes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprefices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprefixes%3B%2Cc0

Comment: U.S. birdwatchers may be familiar with the _coturnix_ (aka Japanese quail—naturalized in Hawaii, Texas, and elsewhere in North America), which has the memorable genus and species name _Coturnix coturnix_. A Google Books search finds a few English-language instances of _coturnices_ but only two instances of _coturnixes_. One of the creeks running through my part of the East Bay carries the Spanish name for quail: Codornices Creek (though the quail in question is the California quail).

Comment: what about Velux windows?